# Why this ODE isn't Bernoulli?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The velocity of a body with mass M in free fall (gravity g) has a drag ($\alpha$) proportional to the squared velocity, so we have :

$$m{dv \over dt}   = mg - \alpha v^2$$

Why isn't this Bernoulli ODE?

Comment: The independent term $mg$? But I don't really know about names of differential equations.

Comment: You need a variable times $dv/dt$ for bernoulli's DE . Not the case here. It is not even Linear ODE as you have a quadratic in $v$ .

Comment: The trick with Bernouilli's equation, is that dividing by a power of the unknown function you get on one side the derivative of a power (in the term with the derivative of $v$) and a power with exactly one more in the exponent (in the term linear in $y$), and the rest not depending on $v$. Then, changing the variable to that power you get a linear equation of order one. If we have an independent term (and not linear term in $v$) this trick will not work.

Comment: @Simar Bernouilli's is typically non-linear, but in a form that certain trick reduces it to a linear equation of order one.

Comment: @ABC I know that . I was just saying that it is not linear as an independent statement, not in context with the first statement :)

Comment: So can we conclude that it is not solvable by any ODE methods ?

Comment: "not solvable by any ODE methods" might be a major statement. Even when one makes it into a precise statement. I don't know, it could still be possible.

Comment: You can solve it by separation of variables.

Comment: @Raskolnikov Yes Right . It was too simple to think much :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no $y$ term, so we would need $P(x) = 0$. But then $g - {\alpha\over m}v^2$ is not of the form $Q(x)y^n$.

Comment: Thanks! I need a y term, it's clear now.